# Spring Boot 2.0.0.M4 and email address as @PathVariable gives HTTP 500 error

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I'm trying to migrate from Spring Boot `1.5.7` to `2.0.0.M4`

This is my rest controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1.0/users")
public class UsersController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;


    @RequestMapping(value = "/validate-username/{username}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
    public void validateUsername(@PathVariable String username) {
        throw new EntityAlreadyExistsException();
    }

...

}
```

This is exception handler:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalControllerExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler
    @ResponseBody
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CONFLICT)
    public Map<String, ResponseError> handleEntityAlreadyExistsException(EntityAlreadyExistsException e, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        logger.debug("API error", e);
        return createResponseError(HttpStatus.CONFLICT.value(), e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

in case of the following username, for example : `alex` everything is working fine and I'm receiving `409` status code with `application/json; charset=UTF-8` as a content type but in case of the following user name, for example, `alex@test.com` my endpoint returns `500` status code and non-JSON content type, something like this:

[image]

I can reproduce this issue when username PathVariable contains `.com` at the end.

I use embedded Tomcat as tbe application server. Woth Spring Boot 1.5.7 the same functionality was working fine. How to make it working with Spring Boot 2.0.0.M4 ?

**P.S.**

I know that sending email addresses as URL parameter is a bad practice. I'm just interested in this particular case.

Comment: This is indeed a very interesting case. I'm looking into it and will post a solution (or explanation) as soon as I find one

Comment: @geoand thanks, I'll really appreciate your help on this issue

Comment: I have identified the exact cause of the issue, and I am in process of finding the appropriate fix :)

Comment: Great, looking forward to your fix!

Comment: can't reproduce the exception, work fine with me

Comment: @alexanoid Solution is now in an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are observing goes deep into the Spring WebMvc internals.

The root cause is that Spring is speculating about the accepted response type. 
In detail, the strategy class that is actually providing the answer for the accepted response type in case of `alex@test.com` is [ServletPathExtensionContentNegotiationStrategy](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/accept/ServletPathExtensionContentNegotiationStrategy.html), which makes a guess based on what is finds in the path.

Due to the fact that `com` is a valid file extension type (see [this](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/httpd/httpd/trunk/docs/conf/mime.types?revision=1752884&view=co)), Spring Boot 2.0.0.M4 tries to use that mime type to convert your response from your `ControllerAdvice` class to that mime type (and of course fails) and therefore falling back to it's default erroneous response.

A first though to getting around this issue would be to you specify the HTTP header `Accept` with a value 
of `application/json`.

Unfortunately Spring 2.0.0.M4 will still not use this mime type because the ServletPathExtensionContentNegotiationStrategy strategy takes precedence over [HeaderContentNegotiationStrategy](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/accept/HeaderContentNegotiationStrategy.html).

Moreover `alex` is used or (even something like `alex@test.gr` for that matter), no mime type is being guessed by Spring, therefore allowing for the regular flow to proceed.

The reason that this works is Spring Boot 1.5.7.RELEASE is that Spring is not attempting to map com to a mime type, and therefore a default response type is used which allows the process of converting the response object to JSON to continue.

The  difference between the two version boils down to [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/dcd2a0395e28c0141be04f7659336f2e246c7518/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/accept/AbstractMappingContentNegotiationStrategy.java#L107) and [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/f4f990b2c900a9b325fd0770d9064a188d073253/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/accept/AbstractMappingContentNegotiationStrategy.java#L153).

Now comes the even more interesting part, which is of course the fix.
I have two solutions in mind, but I will only show the first one and just mention the second.

Here is the first solution which build upon my explanation of the problem.
I admit that this solution does seem a bit intrusive, but it works a like a charm.

What we need to do is alter the auto-configured `ContentNegotiationManager` in order to replace the supplied `PathExtensionContentNegotiationStrategy` with our own custom one. Such an operation can easily be performed by a `BeanPostProcessor`.

```
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager;
import org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationStrategy;
import org.springframework.web.accept.PathExtensionContentNegotiationStrategy;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.NativeWebRequest;

import java.util.ListIterator;

@Configuration
public class ContentNegotiationManagerConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ContentNegotiationManagerBeanPostProcessor contentNegotiationManagerBeanPostProcessor() {
        return new ContentNegotiationManagerBeanPostProcessor();
    }


    private static class ContentNegotiationManagerBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

        @Override
        public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
            return bean; //no op
        }

        @Override
        public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
            if (!(bean instanceof ContentNegotiationManager)) {
                return bean;
            }

            final ContentNegotiationManager contentNegotiationManager = (ContentNegotiationManager) bean;

            ListIterator<ContentNegotiationStrategy> iterator =
                    contentNegotiationManager.getStrategies().listIterator();

            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                ContentNegotiationStrategy strategy = iterator.next();
                if (strategy.getClass().getName().contains("OptionalPathExtensionContentNegotiationStrategy")) {
                    iterator.set(new RemoveHandleNoMatchContentNegotiationStrategy());
                }
            }

            return bean;
        }
    }

    private static class RemoveHandleNoMatchContentNegotiationStrategy
            extends PathExtensionContentNegotiationStrategy {

        /**
         * Don't lookup file extensions to match mime-type
         * Effectively reverts to Spring Boot 1.5.7 behavior
         */
        @Override
        protected MediaType handleNoMatch(NativeWebRequest request, String key) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

The second solution one could implement is leverage the capability of [OptionalPathExtensionContentNegotiationStrategy](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/14563ef24c6a5ef0658af60a489466dbe5e5910c/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java#L641) class which is used by Spring by default.

Essentially what you would need to do is ensure that every HTTP request to your `validateUsername` endpoint would contain an attribute named `org.springframework.web.accept.PathExtensionContentNegotiationStrategy.SKIP` with the value of `true`

Comment: Thank You very much for this detailed answer !!

Answer (score 2):

Try this buddy, `{username:.+}` instead of your `{username}`

EDIT: I've found out that @ is reserved character for URL, and should not be used in URL. You need to encode your URL.

Something like: alex@test.com - > alex%40test.com

source : [Another stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43541440/how-to-pass-an-email-inside-pathvariable-using-spring)

Comment: Did you try inputting `produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE` ?

Comment: This way it produces following error - `TTP Status 406 – Not Acceptable

Type Status Report

Description The target resource does not have a current representation that would be acceptable to the user agent, according to the proactive negotiation header fields received in the request, and the server is unwilling to supply a default representation.`

Comment: Try my first suggestion with @Pathvariable(name="username"), doesn't hurt :P. Also checkout my small research

Comment: Unfortunately still doesn't work even with URLEncoder.encode(EMAIL, "UTF-8")

Comment: No, I think you need to send already encoded email to that RestController and then decode it.

Comment: Yeah, I mean the same. I used  URLEncoder.encode() at the Java client for my API

Answer (score 2):

[This article](https://medium.com/@saishav_io/error-406-while-using-and-email-address-as-a-path-variable-in-spring-boot-8caaefc17c7b) shows how one can stop Spring from using path extensions for content negotiation (worked for me for Spring Boot 1.5.x at least):

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override 
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) { 
        configurer.favorPathExtension(false); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A shortest possible solution is to modify your URL like below

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/validate-username/{username}/"
```

Note: I use slash `'/'` at the end of the URL. So, the URL will work perfectly for any kind of email address or `.com , .us` containing text in your `{username}` path variable.
You don't need to add any kind of extra configuration to your application.